# Maximum likelihood estimation for binomial experiments with unknown number of trials

Tags: probability, optimization, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

Suppose that we want to estimate the value $p$ of a binomial experiment with only knowing that a heads has occurred without any information about the number of trials. How can we write likelihood function for this observation? How can we maximize this function?

Intuitively it seems that the likelihood for all possible $p$ should be the same but it's not possible to write down the exact equation for likelihood.

Comment: The likelihood is the probability that a certain result happened, given the parameter $p$. You must know something additional about the number of trials.

Comment: If the likelihood is proportional to ${n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$, then for known $n$ this is maximised when $p=\frac kn$, while for unknown $n$ it is maximised by $n=k$ and $p=1$.  The second of these is close to useless

Answer (score 1):

anyway the likelihood is the following

$L(p) \propto p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$

with $a$ known (number of Heads observed) and $n \geq a$

If you want to estimate $p$ in a bayesian way, supposing not to have any prior information about the value of $p$ and supposing you are wondering to find the Miminum MSE estimator,

$\hat{p}=\frac{a+1}{n+2}$

to get a number for your estimation, of course you must know the number of trials

Comment: Your answer is for the case where you know the number of trials. But what if you know nothing about number of trials? Can we claim that the outcome is indifferent to all values of p?